# Display drawable icon on TopLeft corner of toggle button

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have toggle button, following are code-

```
<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/header_message_queue_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="123dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_menu_button"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bandeja_40"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/flecha_separador_menu"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textOff="MESSAGE"
                android:textOn="MESSAGE"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Button displays  "MESSAGE" and icon on left side, icon is from drawable. But the icon is displayed exactly the left side, I wanted to display the icon on **TopLeft** corner of toggle buttn.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In toggle button use padding like i added in code to adjust you drawable inside it.

```
   <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/header_message_queue_btn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="123dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_menu_button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bandeja_40"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/flecha_separador_menu"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textOff="MESSAGE"
            android:textOn="MESSAGE"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:paddingRight="90dp"/>
```

Comment: Did it fix your issue?